# GWT/Grails Project Structure

Tags: gwt, grails

Does somebody already have some experience embedding gwt in other
client pages except the standard html file?

I want to use gwt as front end and grails as backend. Communication
should be handled over rest json interface so that is loosely coupled.

How do i structure my project at best? Should I create 2 independend
projects or should I stick them together?

At the beginning I had some problems with debugging my gwt application
as it was part of the grails project. Now I copied the compiled js
script to my webapp folder and included it in a grails page. Debugging
gwt in noserver mode worked ok. The problem is , how do I solve my
deployment later at best as I dont want to copy my js everytime by
hand? Already tried the grails gwt plugin but its difficult to debug the gwt application and I even do not want to use the service stuff provided with the plugin.

I thought its a good idea to have 2 maven modules on for grails and one for gwt. Later 2 war files(one grails, one gwt) will deployed on Tomcat, so I also can change gwt client stuff without deploying grails again. How do i manage the brige from grails to gwt best? Just call the standard html in a div from grails page?

I am using maven for building my project.

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written 2 posts about this topic. In the [first one](http://felipenasc-en.blogspot.com/2010/03/grails-gwt-rock-n-roll-part-1-exploring.html) I show Grails+GWT in the same application, using the Grails Gwt Plugin. It appears you already tried that approach. In the [second post](http://felipenasc-en.blogspot.com/2010/03/gwt-grails-rock-n-roll-part-2-two.html), I show how to do it with 2 seperate applications, talking JSON between each other using RequestBuilder to request the grails app (that serves JSON responses).

For The deployment in production, you should have Maven doing this job for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i am looking for. Did you already tried some json/rest frameworks for gwt? If yes can you suggest some?

Comment: I did not tried others besides Grails. For me, Grails is great for the server side.